# Can Favorite Tags become Ignored without changing that setting?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Recently, I noticed that the number of **Unanswered** questions with **my tags** on a site had suddenly changed from about 2,500 to around 750.

I have traced it back to my "favorite" tag having been removed from my 14 Favorite Tags and instead appearing amongst my Ignored Tags.

I thought it extremely unlikely that I would have done this deliberately or accidentally, so I added it back to my Favorite Tags and removed it from my Ignored Tags.

A short time later I found that the tag had "jumped" from being a Favorite to being Ignored again.

I tried adding two other tags to my Favorites (one shorter and one longer than the problematic one) and they appeared to stick so it does not seem to be the number or length of tags causing this.

Has anyone else seen any of the Favorite Tags they have set show up later under Ignored Tags instead?

The page on which I am seeing this is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions but I would not expect the issue to be site-specific.

Comment: Title doesn't match the body. Title asks a simple "is there a limit?" question while in the body you describe a possible bug. Can you please clarify how the title is related to the bug report? (i.e. I would expect title such as "Favorite tag became ignored on its own".)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've changed the title to something not far from your suggestion

Comment: Thanks, and this is most likely some kind of weird bug, or something you installed on your side (e.g. the SOUP extension) messing up with things.

Comment: I'm not aware of the "SOUP extension" and I try to keep my browsers vanilla, so I'll be surprised if it is anything that I have installed.

Comment: hmm... OK, what is the tag? Is it happening with other tags?

Comment: It was http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop.  I have not observed it happening on any other tags but then I would be unlikely to, until I start looking for it like I am now that I'm convinced I've seen it happen twice.